# Update values of a column using Index & Match (Excel/VBA)

Tags: excel, insert-update, vba

Bellow is part of my codes and my coding is almost done, but now I found a big problem that it's necessary to be corrected.

I use this code on a sheet with over 10000 rows and my purpose is to update a column using Index & Match functions. What it's doing is that it replaces all cells of range in column J with corresponding values from another sheet. The big problem is that I don't want cells that have no matching item be replaced with #N/A and they keep their old values.

What should I do?

```
Dim SourceRange As Range
Dim fillRange As Range

'bellow formula in A1 notation:
'=INDEX('[myWB.xls]Sheet1'!$A:$B;
'IF(INDEX('[myWB.xls]Sheet1'!$A:$A;MATCH(C4;'[myWB.xls]Sheet1'!$A:$A))=C4;
'    MATCH(C4;'[myWB.xls]Sheet1'!$A:$A);
'    NA());
'    2)

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=INDEX([myWB.xls]Sheet1!C1:C2,IF(INDEX([myWB.xls]Sheet1!C1,MATCH(R[-11]C[-12],[myWB.xls]Sheet1!C1))=R[-11]C[-12],MATCH(R[-11]C[-12],[myWB.xls]Sheet1!C1),NA()),2)"

' autofill formula in column
Set SourceRange = Cells(2, 10)
Set fillRange = Range(Cells(2, 10), Cells(10000, 10))

With SourceRange
   .AutoFill Destination:=fillRange, Type:=xlCopy
End With

'replace formula with its value
With Range(Cells(2, 10), Cells(10000, 10))
   .Value = .Value
End With
```

---

### Update

This is my current code with some improvements. Thanks to Rob Anthony for his help.

```
Dim calc As XlCalculation
Dim f as String

With Workbooks(FinalWB.xls).Worksheets(1)  'Worksheet to be updated
    calc = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic  'Ensure automatic calculation is ON
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Copy Column J to Column Z
    Range(.Cells(2, 26), .Cells(10000, 26)).Value = _  ' Col Z =
    Range(.Cells(2, 10), .Cells(10000, 10)).Value      ' Col J

    f = "=if(ISERROR(INDEX([myWB.xls]Sheet1!C1:C2,IF(INDEX([myWB.xls]Sheet1!C1,MATCH(R[-11]C[-12],[myWB.xls]Sheet1!C1))=R[-11]C[-12],MATCH(R[-11]C[-12],[myWB.xls]Sheet1!C1),NA()),2)),RC[16],INDEX([myWB.xls]Sheet1!C1:C2,IF(INDEX([myWB.xls]Sheet1!C1,MATCH(R[-11]C[-12],[myWB.xls]Sheet1!C1))=R[-11]C[-12],MATCH(R[-11]C[-12],[myWB.xls]Sheet1!C1),NA()),2))"

    With Range(.Cells(2, 10), .Cells(10000, 10))
       .FormulaR1C1 = f    'fill formula without Autofill
       .Value = .Value     'replace formula with its value
    End With

    'Delete Column Z
    .Columns(26).EntireColumn.Delete
End With

Application.Calculation = calc
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

'This is above formula. now seems so easy to understand :)
'    f = 
'    "=IF(                                   'if calculations result an error...
'        ISERROR(
'               INDEX([myWB.xls]Sheet1!C1:C2,
'                    IF(
'                      INDEX([myWB.xls]Sheet1!C1,
'                           MATCH(R[-11]C[-12],
'                                [myWB.xls]Sheet1!C1)
'                           )=R[-11]C[-12],
'                      MATCH(R[-11]C[-12],
'                           [myWB.xls]Sheet1!C1),
'                      NA()
'                      ),
'                    2
'                    )
'               ),
'        RC[16],                             'use previousely copied value of the cell...
'        INDEX([myWB.xls]Sheet1!C1:C2,       'else use that calculations 
'             IF(
'               INDEX([myWB.xls]Sheet1!C1,
'                    MATCH(R[-11]C[-12],
'                         [myWB.xls]Sheet1!C1)
'                    )=R[-11]C[-12],
'               MATCH(R[-11]C[-12],
'                    [myWB.xls]Sheet1!C1),
'               NA()
'               ),
'             2
'             )
'        )
'    "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is to copy and paste Column J into a new column (say Z). Then, put this formula into Column J

```
=if(ISERROR(INDEX([myWB.xls]Sheet1!C1:C2,IF(INDEX([myWB.xls]Sheet1!C1,MATCH(R[-11]C[-12],[myWB.xls]Sheet1!C1))=R[-11]C[-12],MATCH(R[-11]C[-12],[myWB.xls]Sheet1!C1),NA()),2)),RC[16],INDEX([myWB.xls]Sheet1!C1:C2,IF(INDEX([myWB.xls]Sheet1!C1,MATCH(R[-11]C[-12],[myWB.xls]Sheet1!C1))=R[-11]C[-12],MATCH(R[-11]C[-12],[myWB.xls]Sheet1!C1),NA()),2))
```

I check to see whether the formula returns a valid value, if it does not, then I put in the value from Column Z (I have assumed that RC[16] is a valid reference for this, from your earlier comment), otherwise I put in the value as calculated.

Without seeing your spreadsheet, it is difficult to see exactly what you are trying to do. It might be possible to shorten this function.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work. if I put, RC[16], ref. to column Z, it actually causes to pass an unrelated number (=content of the cell where column Z crosses that row) to the outer index function as the row number, actually a fake row number for non-existing item. so we won't keep the original value. of course original value still exists in column Z.

Comment: fantastic! it's working... but I should dig into it, your formula is not so obvious to me. I'll try to make a simplified sample of my work to share